How to use the same DTO with different roles in a RESTful API endpoint in Spring Boot?
I have a Spring Boot RESTful API with a PUT endpoint that can be accessed by different roles (ADMIN, MODERATOR, etc.). How to use the same DTO CreateOrUpdateRequest for all roles but with different field validations & serialization rules depending on the user’s role :
public class CreateOrUpdateRequest {
    @NotNull
    private String field1;

    @NotEmpty
    private String field2;

    @NotNull
    @ValidValueOfEnum(enumClass = MyEnum.class)
    private String field3;

}

For example, I want the ADMIN role to be able to update all the fields, but the MODERATOR can only update ‘field3’.

Should I use a DTO per role ?  If so, how can several DTOs be used for the same route and service method?

I've tried the @JsonView approach but the unserialized fields will be null. My Mapstruct mapper will map null fields to null and automatically empty/delete fields :


@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class RequestMapper {
    @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_NULL, nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)
    public abstract void update(CreateOrUpdateRequest request, @MappingTarget MyEntity entity);
}

Is @JsonView the right approach, or is there a better way to handle this in a Spring ?

I could not understand completely how you want to achieve the roles by dto for each fields to update.   I think you must have the roles defined for the user, once API request comes in, based on the logged in user's role impl which role can update/insert/delete a field value?

I have the role defined for the user yes, I'm using GrantedAuthority from Spring Security. The question is about the case where two roles can update but with different @RequestBody (entire fields or partial fields). I hope that's clearer.

you can't define roles at field level of an entity.  you have roles overall for an API. define different api for different roles or else implement the role permissions in the service layer for crud operations.

It seems strange, it's such a basic need. I'm not going to duplicate my crud for each role and end up with different endpoints. I want the same endpoint for each user, but depending on the role only update the authorised fields. Maybe create two DTOs that implement a shared interface and use that interface for the @RequestBody. Apply the validation logic according to the roles in the service.

Not too familiar with mapStruct, but couldn't you implement the mapped fields based on the role? Maybe have a mapper for each role and just resolve the correct mapper (be it in a private method or with a switch expression on an enum grantedauthority) to apply beforehand.

Yes, this part isn't much complicated, it's the @RequestBody part that can actually receive two different DTOs that I don't know how to manage, because I want to do it from the same endpoint. Not duplicate methods in controller. Do you have any advice ?

Do you actually mean two different DTO classes (as in CreateOrUpdateRequest and CreateOrUpdateRequest2)? If you want different validation on the same class based on the users role, you can use validation groups with jakarta.validation.Validator. Spring's @Valid or org.springframework.validation.Validator does not seem to support that use case though. See https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-groups for an example. That will still require seperate mappers obviously.

I'm talking about two different classes, one for each of the roles, even if it means using inheritance. That'll make things a lot easier to maintain, I think.

In that case you probably still won't be able to use @Valid and have to do explicit validation (you should be able to use spring validator though). Since jackson @JsonSubType cannot use the security context, you probably want to have the request body be a jackson JsonNode or Map<String, Object>, map that to your DTO depending on the role (objectMapper, mapStruct or something else), then run validation, and lastly run the mapper to your entity.

Seems so complicated for something so trivial. I'm not too used to Spring yet. What about creating api endpoints by roles like /resources/{id}/admin ?

Assume below service layer is accessed by an API, based on the user's all the roles and permissions each field can be updated.
@Service
public class EntityService {

    @Autowired
    private EntityRepository entityRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService; // Service to get the currently logged-in user

    public void updateEntity(Long entityId, Map<String, Object> updates) {
        // Get the current user
        User currentUser = userService.getCurrentUser();
        Role userRole = currentUser.getRole();

        // Fetch the entity from the database
        Entity entity = entityRepository.findById(entityId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Entity not found"));

        // Perform field-level checks
        if (userRole == Role.USER_A) {
            if (updates.containsKey("field2")) {
                throw new AccessDeniedException("User A cannot update field2");
            }
            // Update field1
            entity.setField1((String) updates.get("field1"));
        } else if (userRole == Role.USER_B) {
            if (updates.containsKey("field1")) {
                throw new AccessDeniedException("User B cannot update field1");
            }
            // Update field2
            entity.setField2((String) updates.get("field2"));
        } else {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Unknown role");
        }

        // Save the updated entity
        entityRepository.save(entity);
    }
}


It will be a single API but based on user's all the permissions defined, validate the permission before updating each field and then allow the operation.

Thank you for your answer! The problem lies not in the update logic, but in the controller, how I validated my fields using @Validated and different DTO ?

Going the route of multiple endpoints and multiple DTO classes, you could implement a @RequestMapping for each role and just pass that DTO and all required information to a common private method or a service method.
An example would be the following MyController.java with some additional classes, either within the same file or move to seperate files:
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/resources/{id}")
class MyController {

    private final Object adminMapper = null;
    private final Object managerMapper = null;

    @PostMapping("/admin")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> adminUpdate(@Valid @RequestBody AdminDto dto, BindingResult result) {
        return update(dto, result, adminMapper);
    }

    @PostMapping("/manager")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('MANAGER')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> managerUpdate(@Valid @RequestBody ManagerDto dto, BindingResult result) {
        return update(dto, result, managerMapper);
    }

    // alternativly the role instead of the mapper
    private ResponseEntity<?> update(UpdateDto dto, BindingResult result, Object mapper) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            // TODO log and/or pass errors to response
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

        // TODO implement rest / call service

        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

}

enum MyEnum {
    FOO, BAR
}

// no default on fields present in both/all implementations necessary
sealed interface UpdateDto {
    default String field1() {
        return null;
    }

    default String field2() {
        return null;
    }

    MyEnum field3();
}

record AdminDto(
        @NotNull String field1,
        @NotEmpty String field2,
        @NotNull MyEnum field3) implements UpdateDto {
}

record ManagerDto(@NotNull MyEnum field3) implements UpdateDto {
}

In this example, the controller decides the mapper to use, but you could also just pass the DTO and the role to a service and let the service handle that instead. Obviously you do not have to use records or sealed interfaces. You could use an (not even necessarily) abstract class that contains field3 and have the admin DTO extend that class:
class UpdateDto {
    // TODO field3
}

class AdminUpdateDto extends UpdateDto {
    // TODO field 1
    // TODO field 2
}

Edit:
As noted, I'm not familiar with MapStruct, so you might have to call that mapper with the actual DTO and not the interface to make sure the null values from the default methods won't be used.
An alternative would be to just have a Consumer as an argument that does mapping and remove the usage of an interface. Or just remove the private method alltogether and live with some code duplication (bindingResult handling, loading entity and mapping).

Thank you for your answer ! That's what I already do, but you have two different endpoints /admin and /manager. My question suggested having just one, but seems not possible ?
